# How to access private Docker Hub repository from Kubernetes on Vagrant

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am failing to pull from my private Docker Hub repository into my local Kubernetes setup running on Vagrant:

> Container "hellonode" in pod "hellonode-n1hox" is waiting to start: image can't be
>   pulled
>
> Failed to pull image "username/hellonode": Error: image username/hellonode:latest not found

I have set up Kubernetes locally via Vagrant as described [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant/) and created a secret named "dockerhub" with *kubectl create secret docker-registry dockerhub --docker-server=https://registry.hub.docker.com/ --docker-username=username --docker-password=... --docker-email=...* which I supplied as the image pull secret.

I am running Kubernetes 1.2.0.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To pull a private DockerHub hosted image from a Kubernetes YAML:

Run these commands:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER=docker.io
DOCKER_USER=Type your dockerhub username, same as when you `docker login`
DOCKER_EMAIL=Type your dockerhub email, same as when you `docker login`
DOCKER_PASSWORD=Type your dockerhub pw, same as when you `docker login`

kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey \
  --docker-server=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER \
  --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER \
  --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD \
  --docker-email=$DOCKER_EMAIL
```

If your username on DockerHub is `DOCKER_USER`, and your private repo is called `PRIVATE_REPO_NAME`, and the image you want to pull is tagged as `latest`, create this `example.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: whatever
spec:
  containers:
    - name: whatever
      image: DOCKER_USER/PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
```

Then run:

```
kubectl create -f example.yaml
```

Comment: Actually works! Have tried all kinds of configs using .dockercfg and .docker/config.json on nodes. Was completely unstable in terms of maintaining docker sessions. +1 thanks for saving me a massive headache! Now, onto ingress controllers! YAY! :P

Comment: Should this work in the same way for an Organization private repo? It keeps failing, not sure if the url for image needs to be different in some way

Comment: Probably something somewhere was changed not so long time ago, with recipe from answer error appears `Failed to pull image "index.docker.io/DOCKER_USER/PRIVATE_REPO/IMAGE_NAME:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for DOCKER_USER/PRIVATE_REPO/IMAGE_NAME, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`. But with changes `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER=docker.io` and `image: PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:latest` everything works fine for me

Comment: thanks @sanddog !! i tried every single way of setting up the secret to be able to pull private images from an organization in dockerhub. Your comment fixed my issue which i was like 2 hours on it. Thanks.

Comment: For those who are idiots like me, add the namespace if you are creating it for namespaced deployments, took me at least half an hour to realise

Comment: FYI, `--docker-email` doesn't seem to be necessary. Also, I recommend using a read-only access token instead of your password from https://hub.docker.com/settings/security

Comment: Also, if you just got "Image pull failure" try deleting the deployment (using k9s or similar is easy) and let it re-deploy. Also, add `myregistrykey` to `kubectl edit serviceaccount` instead of manually adding it to all your deployment yamls.

Answer (score 9):

Create k8 Secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: repositorySecretKey
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <base64 encoded docker auth config>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Then in pod or rc config mention the secret. Example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-pod
      image: quay.io/example/hello:1.1
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: repositorySecretKey
```

Docker auth config

```
{
   "https://quay.io": {
    "email": ".",
    "auth": "<base64 encoded auth token>"
  }
}
```

Or

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey \
    --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER \
    --docker-username=DOCKER_USER \
    --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD \
    --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Comment: Good point: indeed that's lower down in the document I linked to: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod.

Comment: Also you can try something like `kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL`. This will add the secret automatically and you will just need to add `imagePullSecrets` in pod or rc config.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using the following **Kubectl** command :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry your-key-name\
    --docker-server=docker.io \
    --docker-username=DOCKER_USER \
    --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD \
    --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these instructions on [how to configure nodes to authenticate to a private repository](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#creating-a-secret-with-a-docker-config) in order to configure the kubelets to make Docker use your credentials, or follow +Phagun Baya's solution with imagePullSecrets that applies to pods.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is stuck using kubectl from Windows -

```
set secretname="secret1"  
set username="dockerhubUsername"  
set pw="dockerhubPassword"  
set email="dockerhubEmail@domain.com"  

kubectl create secret docker-registry %secretname% --docker-username=%username% --docker-password=%pw% --docker-email=%email%
```