# Kubernetes repeatedly pull image and stay stuck at containercreating

Tags: oracle, docker, kubernetes, containers, minikube

I'm trying to create a Single-Instance Stateful Application along the lines of https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/, with the exception that I would like to use an Oracle database.

I run W10 and use Minikube to set up the cluster, Hyper-V as the driver and I also created a Virtual switch for Minikube.

I edited the deployment YAML accordingly to use Oracle DB image and ports, as well as added a pull secret for Docker Hub (as Oracle wants you to log in to pull the inmage).

The final YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orcldb
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1521
    name: sqlnet
  - port: 5500
    name: oraclexml
  selector:
    app: orcldb
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: orcldb-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: orcldb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: orcldb
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: orcldb
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
        name: orcldb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1521
          name: sqlnet
        - containerPort: 5500
          name: oraclexml
        volumeMounts:
        - name: orcldb-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/orcldb
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: dockerhubkey
      volumes:
      - name: orcldb-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: orcldb-pv-claim
```

So after I run `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`, everything is created accordingly:

```
service "orcldb" created
persistentvolumeclaim "orcldb-pv-claim" created
deployment "orcldb" created
```

But then, if I run `kubectl describe pods orcldb`, I see this in the events:

```
Type     Reason                 Age              From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----             ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling       1h (x2 over 1h)  default-scheduler  PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "orcldb-pv-claim"
  Normal   Scheduled              1h               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned orcldb-7d96df68c8-bjwql to minikube
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1h               kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-c91fd4a0-c3da-11e7-9300-00155d050c0a"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1h               kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-rszmg"
  Normal   Pulling                1h               kubelet, minikube  pulling image "store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1h               kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-c91fd4a0-c3da-11e7-9300-00155d050c0a"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1h               kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-rszmg"
  Normal   Pulling                1h               kubelet, minikube  pulling image "store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  43m              kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-c91fd4a0-c3da-11e7-9300-00155d050c0a"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  43m              kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-rszmg"
  Normal   Pulling                43m              kubelet, minikube  pulling image "store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  32m              kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-c91fd4a0-c3da-11e7-9300-00155d050c0a"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  32m              kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-rszmg"
  Normal   Pulling                32m              kubelet, minikube  pulling image "store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1"
```

Also, the minikube cluster sometimes stops (?) / refuses connection, I usually restart minikube after that, but once I left it be and it came back up afte a while (with the repeating pulling process still going on).

I haven't been able to find anyone facing this kind of issue, so I would greatly appreciate any insigh as to why this might be happening.

Part of the minikube logs with errors about disk:

```
Nov 07 18:37:22 minikube localkube[16252]: E1107 18:37:22.727122   16252 fsHandler.go:121] failed to collect filesystem stats - rootDiskErr: du command failed on /var/lib/docker/overlay2/611dbda511b2771528eff890891445fe89fdd171e6e1e944596b82b5a031d4c6 with output stdout: , stderr: du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/611dbda511b2771528eff890891445fe89fdd171e6e1e944596b82b5a031d4c6': No such file or directory
Nov 07 18:37:22 minikube localkube[16252]:  - exit status 1, rootInodeErr: cmd [find /var/lib/docker/overlay2/611dbda511b2771528eff890891445fe89fdd171e6e1e944596b82b5a031d4c6 -xdev -printf .] failed. stderr: find: '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/611dbda511b2771528eff890891445fe89fdd171e6e1e944596b82b5a031d4c6': No such file or directory
Nov 07 18:37:22 minikube localkube[16252]: ; err: exit status 1, extraDiskErr: du command failed on /var/lib/docker/containers/97fc2e9f49de23415fe6494bf3684672aeb1213930de02314b1f2ce411f4dc6a with output stdout: , stderr: du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/containers/97fc2e9f49de23415fe6494bf3684672aeb1213930de02314b1f2ce411f4dc6a': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is `store`? Is that a hostname? Is it a private repository? Did you add a [pull secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)?

Comment: The Oracle database image didn't seem to be recognized just by oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1, so I added the store/ (as per the Oracle documentation on docker hub, stating that to pull the image you need to run: docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1)

Comment: Never seen it, but sounds like a private registry for the Docker Hub Store. Use the link I included to add your Docker credentials.

Comment: Also the same kind of behavior happened when I tried to follow the original example exactly (so using a mysql image), except that time after about 5 of these pull repeats, the cluster once again stopped responding. Then it briefly came back up and showed that container was created, but then it once again refused any further connections before I was able to test if the database started successfully.

Comment: I did add the pull secret for DockerHub (as mentioned in the OP) following this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232906/how-to-access-private-docker-hub-repository-from-kubernetes-on-vagrant

Comment: That's starting to sound like you may not have enough disk space/memory. But that's just a wild guess. More logs would probably help.

Comment: That actually might be case, I thouhgt of that when my laptop would freeze up when having the container creation running in the background, hoping that it would start. I'm not sure how to find out though, or how do I let minikube use more memory. Minikube logs do show some errors regarding disk (I'll add them to the OP)

Comment: Try: minikube start --help
Example : minikube start --memory 8000 --cpus 2 --kubernetes-version v1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved away from the huge official images by Oracle and used a custom made image of the Oracle Express 11g database. The image is now pulled and container started without any problems.

Also, the issue where Minikube would stop responding after a while was solved by disabling dynamic memory in Hyper-V, as described in this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1762#issuecomment-318365440).

Comment: Did you ever find out if your store reference for the image was correct or not?

Comment: @DonBecker I haven't looked into it further and just used a different image. The official Oracle image is way too large anyways :)