# How to install kubernetes from local registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vagrant

I want to use local registery for my **kubernetes**. I can use [How to access private Docker Hub repository from Kubernetes on Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232906/how-to-access-private-docker-hub-repository-from-kubernetes-on-vagrant) and it works i can pull my image from it but i should use 
image: IP_OF_DOCKER_REGISTERY:5000/IMAGE_NAME

But i do not want it. i want to every image pull form my docker **registery** without assign any IP and port.

What should i do?
How can i use proxy?

Comment: What do you mean by?
"without assign any IP"
You mean IP to Kubernetes or any pod etc running in Kubernetes?

Comment: no IP of docker registery

Comment: I'm still not getting the question. By default, Kubernetes pulls images from hub.docker.com. If you image is public, it works. If image is private [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) helpful to you. Could you please explain more?

Comment: I want to have local hub and for using local hub i should set an  IP of local hub in my template . but i do not want to set IP

Comment: I see that document before. but i do not want to change my template to use local hub . i want to use previous template but using my local registery

Comment: I want to kubernetes use by default my local registery without change my template

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible out-of-the-box with docker, if you want to use a registry different to Docker hub, you have to specify it as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry).

```
$ docker pull <private_registry>/image_name:tag
```

Refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7203) for more information

Comment: how a bout using mirror for docker hub?
i do not know any thing about it .but i think it can work.

Comment: You could end up creating a proxy and either changing the `hosts` file or adding DNS entries to your DNS server to "trick" the docker client into going to your private registry. But I think this commodity is not a common practice that just adds layers of complexity into something that could and should be much simpler and can cause confusion to the people that uses it as they may think they are pulling from docker hub when they are not.

Comment: how can i create proxy?

Comment: If i want to use dns what should i set?
192.168.1.5:5000     DOCKER
what should i set as DOCKER? what name?
if i have docker registery with an IP 192.168.1.5